# Take hex code from specified offset - C#

Tags: c#, hex, offset, system.io.file

I am writing an application that works with hexs of file but not with all of them at ones but only with this with specified offset. To this moment i am using a function taken from here but it doesn't work good in my case.

```
public static string HexStr(byte[] p)
{
    char[] c = new char[p.Length * 2 + 2];
    byte b;
    c[0] = '0'; c[1] = 'x';
    for (int y = 0, x = 2; y < p.Length; ++y, ++x)
    {
        b = ((byte)(p[y] >> 4));
        c[x] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 : b + 0x30);
        b = ((byte)(p[y] & 0xF));
        c[++x] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 : b + 0x30);
    }
    return new string(c);
}

byte[] byVal;
using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    BinaryReader brFile = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
    fileStream.Position = key;
    byte[] offsetByte = brFile.ReadBytes(0);
    string offsetString = HexStr(offsetByte);
    byVal = brFile.ReadBytes(16);
}
```

Can someone suggest any other solutions of this problem ?

P.S. This code takes the hex of file on the specified offset (`fileStream.Position=key` "key" is the offset) and this is my weak spot

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work good in my case"?

Comment: I am working with too much hex to compare with the taken ones also i am looking through many files and its just using one value of CPU and RAM that can't be clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string path = @"C:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long offset = 25;
            long key = offset - (offset % 16);
            using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                BinaryReader brFile = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
                fileStream.Position = key;

                List<byte> offsetByte = brFile.ReadBytes(16).ToList();

                string offsetString = string.Join(" ", offsetByte.Select(x => "0x" + x.ToString("x2")).ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}​
```